# Fluent Api Column order sytax

Tags: many-to-many, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to understand how to put this many to many annotation into fluent api. I just don't know the syntax to represent the column order.

```
public class UserNotification
   {
     [key]
     [Column(Order = 1)]
     public string UserId { get; set;}

     [key]
     [Column(Order = 2)]
     public int NotificationId {get; set;}

     public ApplicationUser User{get; set;}
     public Notification Notification {get; set;}
   }
```

**I know fluent Api will look like this:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<UserNotification>()
     .HasKey(n => new {n.UserId, n.NotificationId});

    // What about the Column Order? 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the `Key` and `Column` data annotations as follows:

> > ***UserNotification*** has a key consisting of **UserId** and **NotificationId** columns, with **UserId** being first and **NotificationId** being second.

i.e. the column order attribute is used only to determine which column is first, second etc. in the context of the composite primary key.

Fluent API does not need that because you describe both the key columns and their order inside the `HasKey` expression:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserNotification>()
   .HasKey(n => new { n.UserId, n.NotificationId });
//                        ^            ^
//                      first        second
```

In other words, you did it correctly, no further action is needed.